# -bash: python setup.py develop: command not found

Tags: python, virtualenv, setuptools

When executing `python setup.py develop`, the console prints

> `-bash: python setup.py develop: command not found`

This happened after removing and recreate the virtualenv with

```
virtualenv -p python3 ENV
source ENV/bin/activate
```

The `setup.py` looks like this

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='my-downloader',
      version='0.1',
      description='download tool',
      url='',
      author='Me',
      author_email='email',
      license='MIT',
      packages=['downloader'],
      package_dir={'': 'src'},
      python_requires='~=3.6',
      entry_points={
          'console_scripts': [
              'download-it=downloader.download:main_func'
          ]
      },
      install_requires=['aiohttp'],
      zip_safe=False)
```

Comment: The fact that bash is complaining about the entire "`python setup.py develop`" command instead of just Python suggests that it's not splitting the command line right and is trying to find a command with the entire line as its name.  Did you mess with bash's `IFS` variable?  Are you somehow typing a non-breaking space in place of a real space?

Comment: I copied the command from OneNote. Now it works if I type the command manually. Thank you for your help!!

Comment: An alternate `IFS` value wouldn't cause this bug unless the command were being run via an unquoted expansion, and that's [an inherently buggy practice](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) regardless.